# BitmapData and JpegEncoder Limitations

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to save out a large image from flash using bitmapdata and the jpegencoder. I am looking into the limitations of this process and have noticed you can only set bitmapdata pizel width and height to a certain amount and this might be flexible with what you set the jpegencoder quality to (1-100).

Does anyone know what the specific limitations of these two things are? I'm basically trying to see just how large of an image I can save out (because I need to use the image exported for printing purposes, so I need it as high quality as possible).

I have read articles that say in fp 10 you can render up to something like 16,000 px. But I tried an image that is 3500 x 3500 and it timed out.  So not sure if this is correct information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image size limit up to Flash Player 9 is 2880x2880, Flash 10 increased this limit to 4096x4096. This applies also for the Stage, Sprites and MovieClips.

The quality used for the JPGEncoder class does not circumvent this limitation as this is tied to the Flash core.

Comment: so how come when i try to draw a bitmap of 4000 x 4000 pixels it times out?  And might there be a workaround or something else effecting this?

Comment: if your target is Flash 9, then it must be throwing an internal exception somewhere. If it's for Flash 10, then it might be an inherent limitation of the JPGEncoder class (the Google Code page for AS3corelib shows this class to be last modified on August 2008, which means there's a chance that some value in there is hardcoded to only support textures of up-to 2880x2880)