# How to enhance the resolution of JPEG encoder

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, image-processing, jpeg

I'm trying to enhance the output JPEG picture using JPEG encoder. 
And by reading this post here at stackoverflow:
[BitmapData and JpegEncoder Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359155/bitmapdata-and-jpegencoder-limitations)
Therefore, there are some limitations.
I am attaching, the JPEG output. [image: output JPEG Picture]

This is the highest rendered image. It isn't enough. How can I increase quality of the image?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I want to render the image in a much more high quality image. @Jonatan Hedborg

Comment: So render it to a higher resolution image. Or is it the lines? JPEG is always going to have trouble showing 1px lines - try saving it as PNG instead, or make the lines thicker.

Comment: What about using PNG instead of JPEG? There's a PNGEncoder too.

Comment: Oh, I see now that Jonatan already suggested PNG. Sorry for posting before reading properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.blooddy.by/) JPEGencoding lib instead. It's faster and doesn't have limitaions. And you didn't say anything about how you stretch your initial object and how you save it.
But I'm 99% sure this lib will help you

Answer (score 0):

When saying "higher quality", do you mean better vector rendering ? Less deterioration when compressing ? Or more pixels ?

Better rendering : you are not getting any, as far as i know.

Less deterioration at compression -> set the JPEGEncoder quality parameter a higher value (100) or make a png (PNGEncoder).

More pixels : Make the `BitmapData` bigger. If you are drawing some object to the `BitmapData` you can either widen the said object. Ore use a `Matrix` with the draw method to scale the result.

It would be helpfull if you would post some more code, or maybe a link to your project sources ...

### EDIT :

Something else i see that may cause you a problem is if you are trying to draw a scaled down bitmap whit it's `smoothing` property set to `false`. Be aware that every time you set a new value to the `bitmapData` property of a `Bitmap`, `smoothing` is set back to `false`

Answer (score 0):

My question would be: are you 1. running into theoretical limitations of the jpeg standard or 2. Are you just using a poor encoder? If you are not sure, compress the same image in photoshop on the highest quality setting and see if it's any better.

In case of 1: You could slightly blur your image prior to compression, which would reduce the artefacts although of course at the cost of blurriness.

In case of 2: clearly use a better encoder!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) ?
You can change its resolutions and convert its formats. It also has command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using  [Render High Resolution Images using VRay or Mental Ray](http://www.cgarena.com/freestuff/tutorials/max/high-res/render.html)

> The end product was a full panoramic image rasterized as a JPEG, which
>   the client was then able to view and navigate through, by using a free
>   software called “ iMove Viewer” .

Script used:-

```
(

            Global AutosaveImg          

            fn dntTick =

            (

                        Local Autosavedir = (getdir #autoback) + "\\" + "Rend_autosave.tif"

                        TIF.setType #color16

                        TIF.setAlpha #true

                        ::AutosaveImg = getLastRenderedImage copy:off

                        AutosaveImg.gamma = 2.2

                        AutosaveImg.filename = Autosavedir

                        Save AutosaveImg

            )

            Global dnetTimer = dotnetobject "system.timers.timer" (2*60*1000)

            dotnet.addEventHandler dnetTimer "Elapsed" dntTick

            callbacks.removeScripts id:#RenderAutoSave

            callbacks.addScript #preRender "dnetTimer.start()" id:#RenderAutoSave

            callbacks.addScript #postRender "dnetTimer.stop()" id:#RenderAutoSave

)
```

To save this script, simply open 3ds Max, followed by clicking on the MAXScript button from the main toolbar, and choosing the MAXScript Editor option from the dropdown list.

[image]

Its dialog should open. Next, copy and paste the above mentioned script onto the dialog’s text field.

By default, the script automatically finds the autosave path with the (getdir #autoback) string of code; and saves the file under the name of  "Rend_autosave.tif"  as a TIF file format.

[image]

This can be changed manually. For instance, the default path could be saved in the following location: C:\Users\Public\Pictures

The relevant line of code would be replaced with the following: “Local Autosavedir = C:\Users\Public\Pictures + "Rend_autosave.tif" .

[image]